# T-Mobile network in Thailand: Koh Phayam?

Tags: thailand, data-plans, roaming

I've read mobile data coverage is spotty on Koh Phayam.

I plan to use the "free" international roaming my American T-mobile plan includes ([Simple Global at "2G speeds"](https://www.t-mobile.com/travel-abroad-with-simple-global)). What networks do they use in Thailand?

They mark the [island as covered](http://The%20island%20is%20marked%20as%20covered%20on) but I'd like to try and find some more specific accounts of using their service or the networks they roam on.

[image: Tmobile coverage map]

Comment: Can you link to the T-mobile's 2G simple global program details? 
 Any particular reason why you wouldn't buy a local sim (AIS, True, Dtac, My Cat, etc)?  2G signals in LoS are much more difficult than 5 years ago; 3g/4g is more common now.

Comment: Would roam instead of mess with a local SIM since I don't pay extra for it.
I think t-mobile might often use 3G/4G networks and throttle to "2G speeds"?

Comment: A local sim is trivially cheap in that part of the world, especially compared to n. american rates. You shouldn't dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: A local sim in Thailand is $1.50, plus $7 for unlimited internet for a month... and that's 3G/4G,  not the "2G speeds" which sound painful.

Comment: Any update on what ended up happening when you came t0 Thailand (Koh phayam or other places)?  How did the roaming work out for you.

Comment: @JonGrah just added an answer - let me know if there's anything I can elaborate on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found out about T-mobile's free roaming while in Thailand:

- It was almost always roaming on AIS. (I think there was also some other operator in some areas around Bangkok.)
- The speed was indeed throttled: the connection would not load all websites well but was enough to occasionally upload a small amount of photos. I even tethered my laptop and made travel bookings successfully on some sites that didn't have mobile versions.
- AIS works perfectly well all over Koh Phayam, I didn't have any issues with network reliability - those concerns are likely outdated. Electricity was also more abundant that expected though it was sometimes off.

For my purposes of light usage I could save the trouble and couple bucks by not buying a local card.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to know for sure as nearly every foreigner I've run into uses a local sim, but it likely will be AIS or TrueMove (True or True-H or TrueMove H).

Other than for accepting an SMS or emergency call, you may be better off with a local SIM (50-100 baht [$1.6-$3.2]). It will usually come with some call credit + free internet for a couple of days, possibly a week or so. You can get extra monthly packages for 200+ baht or the "pro second" plan where you pay internet per mb (25 satang per MB) and voice (1.2 satang per second) for local calls (100 satang = 1 baht; 30 THB ≈ 1 USD); no monthly fees.

If you don't have a dual-sim phone, you would need an extra phone for this strategy if you wish to have both sims active at the same time.

edit:  after evaluating T-mobile's roaming packages for Thailand, it would seem  that you have the "T-Mobile ONE and Simple Choice North America" plan, then your Text and internet is covered (calls are $0.25/min).

[image: tmobile international roaming rates]

But those with "other" plans must first sign up for "World Class Service".  You get $15.00/MB (fifteen USD per Megabyte). $0.50/SMS (outbound) / domestic plan balance (inbound). Voice calls still $0.25/min.

The coverage area seems to be consistent with AIS/True:

[image: tmobile international thailand map]